# Merging two arrays based on element's numerical order

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I try to came up to algorithm for parsing array. What it should do: in input in takes two arrays `first_array=[[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]]` and `second_array=[35, 40]` in output it should return one array `[[10,25], [30,35], [40,45], [50,60]]`. As you guessed it takes `second_array[1]` and compare with `first_array[each][1]` and creates subarray. So far I got (Code Below). Some how in if statement I need two returning. Second argument also could be a multiple array.
 [image]

```js
/*---- First part of problem ----*/
const first_array=[[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]];
const second_array=[35, 40];

const result = first_array.map(record => {
  if (second_array[0] > record[0] && second_array[0] < record[1]) {
    return [[record[0], second_array[0]], [second_array[1], record[1]]]
  } else {
    return record
  }
});

console.log(result)

// result [  [10,25] , [[30,35],[40,45]] , [50,60]  ]
// expect [  [10,25] , [30,35] , [40,45] , [50,60]  ]

/*---- Second part of problem ----*/
const first_array=[15, 60];
const second_array=[[25,30], [30,40], [45,55]];

// [[15, 60]]
// [[15, 25], [30, 60]]
// [[15, 25], [30, 30], [40, 60]]
//output// [[15, 25], [30, 30], [40, 45], [55, 60]]
```

[image]

Comment: What if total count of incrementing numbers will be odd?

Comment: @bigless it's not about odd or event, I need Array(Subarray, Subarray, Subarray) not Array(Subarray(Subsubarray, subsubarray), Subarray)

Comment: I see pairs so I am just asking what for example should be output of `[[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]]` and `[30, 40]`

Comment: `[[10, 25], [30,30], [40,45], [50,60]]`

Comment: Are the input arrays always pre-sorted?

Answer (score 1):

first I join the arrays and after that sorted and split them

```
var a=[[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]]
var b=[35, 40];

var sorted=[].concat.apply([], a,b).sort();

var pairs = [];

for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i += 2)
{
    pairs.push(sorted.slice(i, i + 2));
}
```

Comment: If you want to `sort` numbers, you have to add a callback

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) for the arrays and take the same generator for nested arrays.

Then check if the values are in order and update the result array by checking the lenght of the collector array.

Proceed until both generators return *done*.

```js
function combine(leftArray, rightArray) {

    function* getElements(array) {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < array.length) {
            if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
                yield* getElements(array[i])
            } else {
                yield array[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    function update(value) {
        temp.push(value);
        if (temp.length === 2) {
            result.push(temp);
            temp = [];
        }
    }

    var left = getElements(leftArray),
        right = getElements(rightArray),
        l = left.next(),
        r = right.next(),
        temp = [],
        result = [];

    while (!l.done || !r.done) {
        if (r.done || !l.done && l.value < r.value) {
            update(l.value);
            l = left.next();
            continue;
        }
        if (l.done || !r.done && r.value < l.value) {
            update(r.value);
            r = right.next();
        }
    }
    if (temp.length) {
        result.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(combine([[10, 25], [30, 45], [50, 60]], [[12, 42], [67, 69]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Foor unsorted arrays, you could flat the arrays, sort and group them.

```js
function combine(left, right) {
    const flat = (r, a) => Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(flat, r) : [...r, a];
    return [left, right]
        .reduce(flat, [])
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, a, i) => (i & 1 ? r[r.length - 1].push(a) : r.push([a]), r), []);
}

console.log(combine([[20, 19], [30, 45], [9, 5]], [[12, 42], [67, 69]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @RamzanChasygov, please add other use cases to the question. actually it looks like that the second array is not nested.

Comment: `[1515930300000, 1515956400000], [1515907020000, 1515920400000]` with `[1515906000000, 1515960000000]` returns `[1515906000000, 1515930300000], [1515956400000, 1515907020000], [1515920400000, 1515960000000]` should return `[1515906000000, 1515907020000], [1515920400000, 1515930300000], [1515956400000, 1515960000000]`

Comment: but nice touch with generator

Comment: the arrays are not sorted. is that a change of the specification?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting approach which i expect to be fast.

We have an array scaner function function which works like a map. Takes a function which modifies each element while updating an accumulator which is kept under closure. The function we use here is a sorter which takes to size 2 arrays and order the smallest items in one and the rest in the other. So `sorter([1,5], [3,7])` will result `[1,3]` and accumulator will change to `[5,7]`. Here it is;

```js
var first_array  = [[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]],
    second_array = [28,46],
    merger       = (a,f,t) => a.map((t => e => f(e,t))(t)).concat([t]),
    sorter       = (a,b) => a[1] < b[1] ? a[1] < b[0] ? a
                                                      : a[0] < b[0] ? ([a[1],b[0]] = [b[0],a[1]], a)
                                                                    : ([a[1],b[0]] = [b[0],a[1]], a.reverse())
                                        : a[0] > b[1] ? ([a[0],b[0]] = [b[0],a[0]], [a[1],b[1]] = [b[1],a[1]], a)
                                                      : a[0] > b[0] ? ([a[0],b[1]] = [b[1],a[0]], [a[0],b[0]] = [b[0],a[0]], [a[1],b[1]] = [b[1],a[1]], a)
                                                                    : ([a[1],b[0]] = [b[0],a[1]], b.reverse(), a),
    result       = merger(first_array,sorter,second_array);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` instead of `map`

```
const first_array=[[10,25], [30,45], [50,60]];
const second_array=[35, 40];

const result = first_array.reduce((a, record) => {
  if (second_array[0] > record[0] && second_array[0] < record[1]) {
    a.push([record[0], second_array[0]])
    a.push([second_array[1], record[1]])
  } else {
    a.push(record)
  }

  return a
}, [])

console.log(result)
```